# Problems with accents and special characters in Git

Tags: java, git

This is my first project using Java and Git, so I ask for some comprehension.

The code I'm working in is very simple, I receive a string and I have to do some validations before giving a response, one of the validations is:

```
        if(info.contains("ç"))
        {
            //Here I return some value
        }
        else
        {
            //Here I return a different value
        }
```

The problem is when I Push my changes to the Git server and another programmer pulls my changes to their local repository, the "ç" character is getting replaced by "Ã§"

```
        if(info.contains("Ã§"))
        {
            //Here I return some value
        }
        else
        {
            //Here I return a different value
        }
```

What can I do? Is there some configuration I have to change on Git?

I've done some research without specific answers because all of them talk about accents on the filenames.

I've tried doing this without success

git config --global core.precomposeunicode true

By the way I'm using Eclipse Luna on a Macbook Pro OS Yosemite and the other programmers are using Windows 7 and Eclipse Luna.

Thanks in advance.

Fernando

Comment: This is a character encoding problem. You're saving your source file with a specific character encoding (for example UTF-8) and someone else has their editor or IDE set to a different encoding (for example ISO-8859-1 or Windows 1252). Make sure you use the same character encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Jesper, I'm going to give it a try right now!

Comment: Jesper you were right, thanks for your help. Problem Solved, I don't know how to mark your answer as the solution because it doesn't appear as an answer but as a comment!